# Can't use function return value

Tags: php, mysql, function, authentication, runtime-error

I'm new to PHP and developing a login form. Please find below the code I used. When I tried it gave me the following error:

> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\forsiteSystem\login.php on line 3

Please help me to fix the issue.

Source code for `thems/login.html`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action=".\login.php" method="get">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
                <input type="submit"  id="Submit_button">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Source code for `index.php`:

```
<?php
        // venushka thisara dharmasiri

        require 'config.php';
        require 'thems\login.html';

 ?>
```

Source code for `login.php`:

```
<?php

  if(isset($_POST("Submit_button"))==true)  
      print("Submit button pressed");
  else
      print("submit button sorry");

?>
```

Source code for `config.php`:

```
<?php

$dbUser="root";
$dbPassword="";
$dbName="forsitelogin";
$dbHost="localHost";

$dbConnection= mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPassword);

if($dbConnection)
{
    mysql_select_db($dbName);
    //print("Sucessfully connected to database");
}
else
    die("<strong>Cound not connect to database </strong> ");

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error the script returns explains it:

> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forsiteSystem\login.php on line 3

If you don’t understand the meaning of the error—and believe me, most error messages are bizarre even to experienced programmers—look at the line number referenced.  And looking at line 3 in `login.php` shows me the error; `$_POST("Submit_button")` is invalid:

```
if(isset($_POST("Submit_button"))==true)  
    print("Submit button pressed");
else
    print("submit button sorry");
```

It should be `$_POST["Submit_button"]`:

```
if(isset($_POST["Submit_button"])==true)  
    print("Submit button pressed");
else
    print("submit button sorry");
```

But looking at it further, why is there an `==true`? It can simply be like this:

```
if(isset($_POST["Submit_button"]))  
    print("Submit button pressed");
else
    print("submit button sorry");
```

But I would recommend doing a better check on that value like this:

```
if(array_key_exists("Submit_button", $_POST) && !empty(trim($_POST["Submit_button"])))  
    print("Submit button pressed");
else
    print("submit button sorry");
```

I find that using [`array_key_exists`](https://www.php.net/array_key_exists) and a combination of [`!empty`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) with [`trim`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) works better for basic user submitted data verification.

Answer (score 11):

Should be `$_POST["Submit_button"]` instead of `$_POST("Submit_button")`

Comment: True, but please expound. :)

Comment: `$_POST` is a global array , but OP is calling it like a function.

Answer (score 1):

First some code clean up might help.  PHP does not require braces in `if() else` syntax; however, a great place to start. I would suggest diving into basic syntax of PHP [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.php).  Not that what is there would not work.

```
if(condition){
//do something
} else {
//do something else
}
```

The main issue you are experiencing is proper syntax for arrays in PHP.  Thus this will solve your fatal error.

```
//old
$_POST("Submit_button")

//new
$_POST['foo']
```

This fixes your first fatal error; conversely, will not get you much further.  Since your form is using '**GET**' not '**POST**' to send the variables to the script. The submit button does not return a variable; rather, use another `<input>` or add a name to the form `<form name="form" action="file.php" method="post">` to retrieve a variable. Hence using:

```
if(isset($_POST['form'])){
  echo $_POST['name'];
}
```

Furthermore, there are many concerns using `$_GET` variables and `mysql_connect`.  I would suggest using Google to find some good tutorials on PHP **mysqli** or **PDO** before moving on.